# Zend Framework 2 Navigation Sub-Sub menu

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2

Say that I have the following navigation:

```
Home
Internal
    Folders
        New Folder
    Configuration
        Categories
            New
        Tags
            New
        Options
            New
    Contact
External
```

The code I used in my layout.phtml to show this menu:

```
$internal = $this->navigation('navigation')->findOneByLabel('Internal');
echo $this->navigation('navigation')
          ->menu()
          ->setUlClass('nav nav-list')
          ->setMaxDepth(1)
          ->renderMenu($internal);
```

so it shows like this:

```
Folders
    New Folder
Configuration
    Categories
    Tags
    Options
Contact
```

At the moment I'm getting a decent menu, showing all the parents and the first childs, so the 'New' navigation is never showing.

However, if I'm on the page 'Categories' I want to show their childs too, so the 'New' under the 'Categories' should be showing, like the following:

```
Folders
    New Folder
Configuration
    Categories
        New
    Tags
    Options
Contact
```

I have tried many ways to try this, and have checked all the options (setMinDepth, setMaxDepth, renderSubMenu, setParentMenu) you can give to the menu in the layout.phtml, without succes. It's either the 'New' included, or not included, not something in between.

The documentation about ZF2 is not giving me anything about how to get this sub menu working, apart from making a partial.

So, is making a partial the only option for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small project a while ago, I have made something as a really quick fix. We've been planning to clean up the code and make it configurable, but we never get to another project where we required the same.

TL;DR: You cannot use the normal zf2 view helper but you have to look up the "top" level page you want to display (Internals in your case) and display the menu below that page.

```
<?php

namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class SubNavigation extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($class = null)
    {
        $view = $this->getView();
        $menu = $view->navigation()->menu();

        $container = $view->navigation()->getContainer();
        $active    = $view->navigation()->setRenderInvisible(true)->findActive($container);

        if (!$active) {
            return;
        }

        $container = $active['page'];
        $depth     = $active['depth'];

        while (0 !== $depth) {
            $container = $container->getParent();
            $depth--;
        }

        $visible = $container->isVisible();
        $html    = $menu->setContainer($container->setVisible(true))
                        ->setUlClass('')
                        ->setOnlyActiveBranch(false)
                        ->setMinDepth(null)
                        ->setMaxDepth(null)
                        ->render();

        $container->setVisible($visible);

        if (strlen($html)) {
            return sprintf('<ul %s><li%s><a href="%s">%s</a>%s</li></ul>',
                    (null !== $class) ? ' class="' . $class . '"' : null,
                    ($container->isActive())? ' class="active"' : null,
                    $container->getHref(),
                    $container->getLabel(),
                    $html);
        }
    }
}
```

This view helper renders the "Internal" as a top menu-item in the `sprintf()` call, but you can easily alter this behaviour. You can just echo `$html` and then it's what you actually need.

Comment: FYI, I included in the the Soflomo\Common library this helper a few days ago. Make sure you rely on at least 0.3.1: https://github.com/Soflomo/Common